# Periscope consumer key and secret

Tags: api, twitter-oauth

I'm making login through closed **periscope** api. I'm making POST request at https://api.periscope.tv/api/v2/loginTwitter

Request body

```
{
    "bundle_id": "com.bountylabs.periscope",
    "phone_number": "",
    "session_key": "<twitter_user_oauth_key>",
    "session_secret": "<twitter_user_oauth_secret>",
    "user_id": "<twitter_user_id>",
    "user_name": "<twitter_user_name>",
    "vendor_id": "81EA8A9B-2950-40CD-9365-40535404DDE4"
}
```

What is twitter_user_oauth_key and twitter_user_oauth_secret? How can I get periscope consumer key and consumer secret?

Comment: i also looking for the same

Comment: i think Periscope's API is not public

Answer (score 0):

You could get it by twitter API.  First of all, you should apply for a app by [Twitter Developer](https://developer.twitter.com), then you need to create a app. Final, you will get a session_key, session_secret.